# Custom date format in silverlight binding

Tags: silverlight, format-string

Trying to format a datetime bound value in my XAML using Silverlight 5 like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactDate, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat={}{0:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}" Margin="5,0" />
```

I'm getting the following error:
Unexpected Token after end of Markup Extension.

This is driving me insane!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
    Text="{Binding ContactDate, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"

Unless you mean that you want singlequotes before and after the date string.

Comment: No, I don't want single quotes to display. Your format string at least compiles without error but now it is simply ignoring it. The value is still displayed as 2012/02/29 00:00:00, completely unformatted.

Comment: In that case it is possible that somewhere in your code the ContactDate property is being cast as a string before the DataBinding has a chance apply the formatting, because I am using a very similar binding. Can you put a debug breakpoint on the binding and verify that the source is a DateTime at the time databinding?

Comment: Thanks Boluc, you were right. I was actually deliberately casting it as string in a custom entity created dynamically with a linq query. Eventually had to write a small converter as ContactDate would often have nulls in it and this was the only way I could get it to work.